# Devise: Completed 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, mailer

Previously, I had no issues with Devise sending email confirmations to newly registered users in my Rails app.

Recently I changed the password of the mailer and updated the rails app to include the updated password in my application.yml file.  Now, whenever I try to register a user and send a confirmation email, the email doesn't ever seem to be sent (I know this because I don't receive the confirmation and it doesn't show up in the "sent" folder of my mailer account).  I also get a **Completed 401 Unauthorized** message in my logs.

Anyone know how to fix this?  Complete logs below:

```
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"yqC4atQ1Ma8TCvMWBU+u1uCih5zEaCU1gms5FXwdiH8=", "user"=>{"username"=>"testuser2", "email"=>"testuser@test.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
#<User id: nil, email: "testuser@test.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$FwdfSCcBlGSy7xlxwabk1eI1sP/QNnT13Aw3sTnLvsdO...", reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: nil, confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, authentication_token: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, username: "testuser2", avatar: nil, notifications_viewed_at: nil, about_me: nil>
(2.1ms)  BEGIN
User Exists (17.5ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'testuser@test.com' LIMIT 1
User Load (5.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."authentication_token" = 'i2zA7pTvuADyZwtbjLQB' LIMIT 1
User Load (9.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = 'c458bfc8a3cd8a6d3083e6464872753e7f9670b2828df463a9030186af8f2de7' LIMIT 1
    2014-02-14T20:10:59.099332+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (109.1ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("about_me", "authentication_token", "avatar", "confirmation_sent_at", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "created_at", "current_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "email", "encrypted_password", "failed_attempts", "last_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_ip", "locked_at", "notifications_viewed_at", "remember_created_at", "reset_password_sent_at", "reset_password_token", "sign_in_count", "unconfirmed_email", "unlock_token", "updated_at", "username") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19, $20, $21, $22, $23, $24) RETURNING "id"  [["about_me", nil], ["authentication_token", "i2zA7pTvuADyZwtbjLQB"], ["avatar", nil], ["confirmation_sent_at", Fri, 14 Feb 2014 15:10:58 EST -05:00], ["confirmation_token", "c458bfc8a3cd8a6d3083e6464872753e7f9670b2828df463a9030186af8f2de7"], ["confirmed_at", nil], ["created_at", Fri, 14 Feb 2014 15:10:58 EST -05:00], ["current_sign_in_at", nil], ["current_sign_in_ip", nil], ["email", "testuser@test.com"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$FwdfSCcBlGSy7xlxwabk1eI1sP/QNnT13Aw3sTnLvsdOya505O1w6"], ["failed_attempts", 0], ["last_sign_in_at", nil], ["last_sign_in_ip", nil], ["locked_at", nil], ["notifications_viewed_at", nil], ["remember_created_at", nil], ["reset_password_sent_at", nil], ["reset_password_token", nil], ["sign_in_count", 0], ["unconfirmed_email", nil], ["unlock_token", nil], ["updated_at", Fri, 14 Feb 2014 15:10:58 EST -05:00], ["username", "testuser2"]]
Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (1.4ms)
    Sent mail to testuser@test.com (672.6ms)
    (5.9ms)  COMMIT
    (8.5ms)  BEGIN
    (15.6ms)  COMMIT
    Completed 401 Unauthorized in 2966.9ms
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => ENV['DEV_HOST_URL'] }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => "gmail.com",
    :authentication => :login,
    :user_name => ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"], 
    :password => ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
  }
```

Comment: My first quick diagnosis for things like this: try changing the password to as simple a password (e.g. no "special" characters if they can be avoided) as possible and try again -- I've seen a few different systems choke on odd password characters.

Comment: thanks for your advice.  I tried this but unfortunately it didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: wow, what a silly mistake.  I had made adjustments to my environment variables in application.yml but did not restart the server.  after doing so, it worked!

Comment: Ah! I was just about to ask if you'd done that :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you reload/restart your server? The yml file will not be reloaded on save or change. These files are only read at startup time of the app.